# How to deploy only the presentation layer in JBOSS?

Tags: deployment, jboss, layer, presentation

Just want to ask if how to deploy only the presentation layer? Im still new in using JBoss, so at the moment I am deploying all the layers, and I realize that only for some time I change on the presentation layer, so I dont want to deploy other layers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [JBoss Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools) plugin for eclipse to keep your source folders and the deployment in sync, so you will not have to deploy at all.

If this is not an option for you, you will have to separate the layers into projects which you can then deploy separately. A single project for the backend and a project for the frontend is a simple and common separation pattern.